# How to make a Frontier demo for running Ethereum smart contracts?

Tags: frontier, ethereum, frontier-node-template

Inside the Frontier repo, I found this template folder:
https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/tree/master/template

and its Readme says: `This template is maintained in the Frontier project repository, and can be used to generate a stand-alone template for use in an independent project via the included template generation script.`... This is Option 1. That is to manually run that script.

But then further down that Readme, it says `To build the chain, execute the following commands from the project root:...` this is Option 2. That is to build it via `cargo build --release`

Also I am aware of @JoshOrndorff's tutorial about how to add Frontier into a Substrate Node Template: https://github.com/PureStake/substrate-node-template/commits/frontier-workshop-2021, but that is a few months old. This is Option 3: that is to add Frontier code to the latest Substrate Node Template...

I am very confused by those options.

After fixing the Frontier with the correct Substrate version I need, how can I build a demo for running Ethereum smart contracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved] here are the steps to take:

Go into the Frontier repo

Fix the Substrate version to what you need: like polkadot-v0.9.24

Open this file repo/template/runtime/src/lib.rs

Change your default chainId from 42 to something else, for example 1942. Because 42 is also the Kovan's chainId. I have no idea why the chainId was set to 42.

Then build it and run it:

```
cargo build --release
./target/release/frontier-template-node --dev
```

That runs a chain based on Substrate Node Template.

The hidden port is actually 9933, so here is the correct URL to connect your MetaMask, Hardhat, Remix to the running chain.

```
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:9933",
      chainId: 42,
```

Setup your Polkadot UI

Open Polkadot UI in your browser at https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#?rpc=ws://127.0.0.1:9944

Copy the polkadot UI setting at https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/tree/master/template

Go to Polkadot UI > Settings > Developer tab:
Paste the copied setting

#### To clarify when to use the Frontier's template folder:

- If you have another repo that uses Frontier as a dependency, then use Option 1 above with Josh's video.
- If you want to run Ethereum smart contracts inside a substrate based chain with minimum effort, use Option 2 above and my steps above.